# Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in

Tags: php, eregi

I'm trying to submit values to the database but i get an error message

> Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in
>   C:\wamp\www\OB\admin_add_acc.php on line 20 and 27

Here is the code:

```
<?php       

include 'db_connect.php'; 

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))           
{            
$acc_type=ucwords($_POST['acc_type']);
$minbalance=ucwords($_POST['minbalance']);                       
if (!eregi ("^[a-zA-Z ]+$", stripslashes(trim($acc_type))))//line 20 
{                 
echo "Enter Valid Data for Account Type!";                
exit(0);                 
}           
else 
{                  
if (!eregi ("^[0-9 ]+$", stripslashes(trim($minbalance))))//line 27
{
```

Comment: Use `preg_match` instead of `eregi`

Comment: Well.. that's because `ereg*` functions are deprecated. That exactly what [manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php)

Comment: so many duplicates to this. *sooooooo* many.

Comment: Just add @ in front of the function. e.g.

@ereg()

Comment: For others like me that find this post here, and just need to check for 1 word, instead of `if(eregi('VERIFIED', $info)) {` use `if(preg_match('/VERIFIED/i', $info)) {`. The [i flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-examples) indicates a case-insensitive search. Guess this helps too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`eregi()`](https://php-legacy-docs.zend.com/manual/php5/en/function.eregi) is deprecated as of PHP 5.3, use [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead.

Note that `preg_match()` is only case insensitive when you pass the `i` modifier in your regular expression.

```
include 'db_connect.php'; 
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))           
{            
    $acc_type=ucwords($_POST['acc_type']);
    $minbalance=ucwords($_POST['minbalance']);
    
    // Removed A-Z here, since the regular expression is case-insensitive                
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-z ]+$/i", stripslashes(trim($acc_type))))//line 20 
    {                 
        echo "Enter Valid Data for Account Type!";                
        exit(0);                 
    }           
    else 
    {                  
        // \d and 0-9 do the same thing
        if (!preg_match("/^[\d ]+$/", stripslashes(trim($minbalance))))//line 27
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation):

> Deprecation is a status applied to a computer software feature, characteristic, or practice indicating it should be avoided, typically because of it being superseded.

Take a look at the PHP manual for [eregi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php). As you can see, it has the following warning:

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Further down the page there is some advice on what to use instead:

> eregi() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. preg_match() with the i (PCRE_CASELESS) modifier is the suggested alternative.

So you can use the [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer [here in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php).Since its a Deprecated function in the php version you are using you will get that warning.Instead of `ergi` you can use `preg_match`.See the manual for [preg match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)